# Get Easter-Sunday in Powershell

Tags: algorithm, powershell, math

I want to build a function to test if today is a workday or weekend/holiday.
So I headed over to german wikipedia and tried to recreate that Easter Formular from Gauß:

```
Function Test-Workday {
  Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]$Date = (Get-Date))

  Process {
    $Date = Get-Date -Date $Date
    
    # Ergänzte Osteformel
    # https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Osterformel#Eine_erg%C3%A4nzte_Osterformel
    
    # Floor abrunden, Ceiling aufrunden
    # https://germanpowershell.com/mathematische-funktionen/
    
    $X  = $Date.Year
    $K  = [math]::Floor($X / 100)
    $M  = [math]::Ceiling(15 + (3 * $K + 3) / 4 - (8 * $K + 13) / 25)
    $S  = [math]::Ceiling(2 - (3 * $K + 3) / 4)
    $A  = $X % 19
    $D  = (19 * $A + $M) % 30
    $R  = [math]::Floor(($D + $A / 11) / 29)
    $OG = 21 + $D - $R
    $SZ = [math]::Ceiling(7 - ($X + $X / 4 + $S) % 7)
    $OE = 7 - ($OG - $SZ) % 7
    $OS = $OG + $OE
    
    if ($OS -gt 31) {
      $Day = $OS - 31
      $Month = 4
    } else {
      $Day = $OS
      $Month = 3
    }
    $EasterSunday = (Get-Date -Year $X -Month $Month -Day $Day)
    
    # Feiertagsliste Hashtable: Tag des Jahres .Name (Index), Feiertag .Value
    $Holiday = @{(Get-Date -Year $X -Month  1 -Day  1).DayOfYear = "Neujahr"
                 (Get-Date -Year $X -Month  1 -Day  6).DayOfYear = "Heilige Drei Könige"
                             $EasterSunday.AddDays(-2).DayOfYear = "Karfreitag"                                        
                             $EasterSunday.AddDays( 1).DayOfYear = "Ostermontag"
                 (Get-Date -Year $X -Month  5 -Day  1).DayOfYear = "1. Mai"                                        
                             $EasterSunday.AddDays(39).DayOfYear = "Christi Himmelfahrt"                                        
                             $EasterSunday.AddDays(50).DayOfYear = "Pfingstmontag"                                        
                             $EasterSunday.AddDays(60).DayOfYear = "Fronleichnam"
                 (Get-Date -Year $X -Month 10 -Day  3).DayOfYear = "Tag der Deutschen Einheit"
                 (Get-Date -Year $X -Month 11 -Day  1).DayOfYear = "Allerheiligen"
                 (Get-Date -Year $X -Month 12 -Day 24).DayOfYear = "Heiligabend"
                 (Get-Date -Year $X -Month 12 -Day 25).DayOfYear = "1. Weihnachtstag"
                 (Get-Date -Year $X -Month 12 -Day 26).DayOfYear = "2. Weihnachtstag"
                 (Get-Date -Year $X -Month 12 -Day 31).DayOfYear = "Sylvester"
    }
    
    # Prüfe auf Wochenende (Anfangsbuchstabe Samstag/Sonntag)
    If(($Date).DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0,1) -eq "S") { 
      $Workday = $False 
    } else {
      # Prüfe auf Feiertag
      $Workday = (-Not ($Holiday.ContainsKey($Date.DayOfYear)))
    }
    
    # Werktrag $True sonst $False
    Return $Workday
  }
}
```

After a few tests, it seems to work.. but does it for real?

To get the exact same numbers as in the examples from the wikipedia article, I had to round the numbers up and down (floor/ceiling) here and there but that's why I'm insecure if it's **really** correct...

Also, is it ok to use hasthables like that? I planed to use the holidays Name but eventually decided otherwise.
The ContainsKey-Test seems to be faster than going through an array tho.

Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: What's your actual question? Your question belongs more to [https://codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) I think. ;-)

Comment: If you change the last line of code from this [dfinke/Get-DateOfEaster.ps1](https://gist.github.com/dfinke/8a21ebbdc419b1fd70cf) to `(Get-Date -Day $this.c21 -Month $this.c22 -Year $this.c3 ).ToLongDateString()` it works even on a German system. ;-)

Comment: @Olaf The question is if the algorithm is right: _it seems to work.. but does it for real?_. As an algorithm question, it's on-topic.

Comment: Interesting problem; time and calendar calculations are always tricky. However, you can easily determine if it's correct, since there is only a relatively short list of actual Easter Sundays. Try verifying the output for, say, 1900 through 2100.